# Using native sql in a batch insert

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using JPA and Hibernate as provider So considering the code below where i use the native sql to insert 10000 record , I construct a string of the values to be inserted. So My question is :

1. It's a good implementation ?
2. will I get some memory exception ?
3. Can i insert directly values from a select ? because the loop which
   construct my string of values take some time.
4. there is a best alternative ?

My approche:

```
@Transactional  
public void update_notification(...){

  List<AppelOffre> aos_new = find_ao_with_alerte(choixalerte , contact);

  String values ="";

  int size = aos_new.size() , i = 1;
  for(AppelOffre ao : aos_new){

    values += "(" + ao.getIdAppelOffre() + " , " + contact.getIdConatct() + ")" ;
    if( (i++) != size )
        values += " , " ;

  }

  entityManager.createNativeQuery(" insert into ao_notif (ID_APPEL_OFFRE,ID_CONATCT) 
                                  values " + values )
             .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Yes, you can insert directly from a select.  Most (all?) RDBMSs have bulk-load utilities that can do basic inserts into tables for you, although I'm not sure if JPA exposes these directly.  Note that you should still be using parameterized queries, even here...

Comment: JPA 2.1 provides the ability to load up data via a script, so no need to use native queries

Comment: Can u give a example ? And in my case i have to insert data which come from a select as montioned in my code question not from a script.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse but the data come not from a user or browser.

Comment: @Youssef - If it contains text from anything but one of the system tables, **period**, it's suspect (Actually, I'm wondering if you could name a table `"drop table User; --"`...).  User comment table?  Product description table?  If it contains text that isn't reviewed before concatenation, you run the risk of SQL injection.  If the data is sourced from a table(s), a statement like `INSERT (<columnList>) SELECT <columnList> FROM....` is going to be pretty much the fastest way to do it, pulling the data into the application layer is a fast way to slow things down.

Comment: An example of JPA 2.1 load by script is easily found by using internet search

Comment: it has nothing to do with my question i think this load by script thing till u don't give more example because my data come from select not from script this is why i didn't search at first place.